# OSPF Router ID election query

Tags: routing, ospf

I have a query regarding ospf router id election.

- Suppose I have a router with 3 connected interfaces.

  1. 10.1.1.0/24
  2. 11.1.1.0/24
  3. 12.1.1.0/24
- I have enabled ospf area 0 on network 10.1.1.0 and 11.1.1.0.
- If router id is not manually configured, which one will the router
  id.
- Would it be 12.1.1.0/24 or 11.1.1.0/24.
- My confusion here is, would the router id be highest ip address on
  the physical interfaces or highest ip address of the physical interface where ospf is enabled ?

Comment: That depends on how the router vendor has implemented its selection process. There is no standard that says how the selection process works, and it could be that you end up with a router ID that is not even one of the addresses you have detailed.

Comment: It will select 12.1.1.0/24 as router I'd because it's choses highest ip address on any interface of ospf enabled router